# ¿Cómo se puede tomar el valor de un input y utilizarlo para llamar a una variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

voy iniciando en Python y me surgió una pregunta al querer practicar, pero no se si se pueda hacer.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al solicitarle un valor al usuario, ese valor lo pueda utilizar tome el valor de una variable. Pienso que con un ejemplo me explicaría mejor. Sería lo siguiente:

```
a = 1
b = 10
c = 100
enemigo = int(input('\n Ingrese la vida del enemigo: '))

print('\n La vida del enemigo es ' + str(enemigo))

while enemigo > 0 and enemigo < 10000:
    
     
    print ('\n\n **** Utilice a, b o c para seleccionar el ataque deseado **** \n')
    player = input(' Seleccione el ataque que quiere utilizar: ')
        
    
    if  player != "a" or player != "b" or player != "c":
        print ('\n Por favor, selecciona un ataque valido')
        continue 
    
    elif player == "a" and enemigo > 10:
        enemigo -= a
        print('\n El ataque es demasiado debil para causar daño a este enemigo, por favor utiliza otro ataque')
        continue
    
    elif player == "b" and enemigo > 100:
         enemigo -= b
         print('\n El ataque es demasiado debil para causar daño a este enemigo, por favor utiliza otro ataque')
         continue
    
    elif player == "c" and enemigo > 1000:
        enemigo -= c
        print('\n El ataque es demasiado debil para causar daño a este enemigo, por favor utiliza otro ataque')
        continue
        
    elif enemigo - player > 0:
            print ('\n Le has quitado ' + str(player) + ' puntos' )
            print ('\n La vida restante del enemigo es de ' + str((enemigo - player)+player) + ' puntos')
    
    elif enemigo <= 0:
        print ('\n Felicidades, lo has matado')  
        break

if enemigo > 10000:
   
   print('\n Eres demasiado débil para causarle daño a este enemigo, por favor vuélvete más fuerte')
```

Ese es el código que estoy haciendo jeje. También me había surgido un problema de que al ingresar al principio (antes de que se me ocurriera lo de a, b o c) al ingresar el ataque del jugador, al momento de restarla a la vida del enemigo, se restaba el doble. La solución que encontré fue sumarle el ataque del jugador.

print ('\n La vida restante del enemigo es de ' + str((enemigo - player)**+player**) + ' puntos')

En la parte de negritas.

Si tienen alguna sugerencia y me pueden ayudar con mi duda, estaría perfecto. De antemano gracias.
(Se que se puede mejorar el código que hice jeje, pero es para practicar ya que estoy iniciando)
Saludos

Comment: lo siento no entendí tu pregunta, podrías explicarla un poco mejor? ademas cual es el problema que presentas?, si es necesario agrega un ejemplo de lo que quieres que pase

Comment: Claro que si, no me expliqué muy bien la verdad. Lo que quiero es que al introducir la letra "a", "b" o "c" en el input, pueda utilizarla para que ese pueda tomar el valor de su variable y que sea el valor del ataque. Que al introducir la letra "a" el ataque sea de 1, al introducir la letra "b" el ataque sea de 10. No se si me haya podido explicar un poco mejor.

Comment: Bueno ahora si que te entendi, ahora publico mi respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para hacer lo que pides vamos a usa un diccionario, aunque puedes usar la estructura de datos que desees, solo tendrás que adaptarlo, un problema que encontré es que, la vida del enemigo no se guarda. además tu problema de *se resta el doble* es por que cuando dices que el ataque es muy débil de igual forma restas la vida. Bueno vamos con la solucion

Primero definimos una estructura de datos de un diccionario para los ataques

```py
ataques = {"a":1,"b":10,"c":100}
```

Luego definí mejor el ciclo `while` reemplazando la expresión `enemigo > 0 and enemigo < 10000` por `while enemigo in range(10000)` que es su equivalente.

Bueno, al tener una mejor estructura de datos, nos facilita la simplificacion del codigo, para verificar si el ataque existe podemos comprobar que este en el diccionario con un `if ataque in ataques`, solo negamos para saber si no se encuentra `if ataque not in ataques`.

Para acceder al valor de un diccionario se hace de la misma forma como si de una lista se tratase `diccionario[key]`, sabiendo que un diccionario se compone de clave/valor `{key:value}`

Bueno vamos con la simplificación del codigo

```py
#pedimos los datos
enemigo = int(input('\n Ingrese la vida del enemigo: '))
print('\n La vida del enemigo es ' + str(enemigo))

#entramos al ciclo
while enemigo in range(10000):
    print ('\n\n **** Utilice a, b o c para seleccionar el ataque deseado **** \n')
    player = input(' Seleccione el ataque que quiere utilizar: ')
      
    #verificamos si no esta en la lista  
    if  player not in ataques:
        print ('\n Por favor, selecciona un ataque valido')
        continue 
    
    elif enemigo - ataques[player] > 0:
            vida = enemigo - ataques[player]#guardamos la vida
            enemigo = vida #cambiamos la vida del enemigo
            print ('\n Le has quitado ' + str(ataques[player]) + ' puntos' )
            print ('\n La vida restante del enemigo es de ' + str(vida) + ' puntos')
            #verificamos si lo hemos matado
            if enemigo <= 0:
                print ('\n Felicidades, lo has matado')  
                break
    #verificamos la potencia del ataque
    elif ataques[player] > enemigo:
            print('\n El ataque es demasiado debil para causar daño a este enemigo, por favor utiliza otro ataque')
    #no se cuando entra a este bucle, pero de igual forma restamos la vida y verificamos si hemos ganado
    else:
        ataque = ataques[player]
        enemigo -= ataques[player]
        if enemigo <= 0:
            print ('\n Felicidades, lo has matado')  
            break        
#en caso el enemigo sea muy poderoso, ya fuimos :/
if enemigo >= 10000:
    print('\n Eres demasiado débil para causarle daño a este enemigo, por favor vuélvete más fuerte')
```

Lo siento por no haber entendido la ultima parte, por qui donde estoy es de noche. Si tienes alguna dudo o sigues tenido un problema avísame, te ayudare. EL código aun se puede simplificar un poco, pero eso te lo dejo a ti :)

Comment: Era justo que lo que quería hacer, te lo agradezco. Respecto a lo del almacenamiento de la vida, creía que al momento de utilizar `enemigo -= ataque` se iba almacenando la vida. Gracias de nuevo :D

Comment: en realidad si, es lo mismo que `enemigo = enemigo - ataque`, pero eso causaba que  se restara doble, el error creo que estaba en mostrar los datos en el `elif enemigo - player > 0:`, igual todo esta arreglo en el código que te deje

Comment: Ahhhh entonces por eso se me restaba el doble xd, como no sabía por qué pasaba le tuve que sumar de nuevo un ataque.

Comment: cuando no sepas que pasa un `print()` ayuda mucho, aun que mejor es debuguear el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debe hacer es asignar a una variable el valor seleccionado

```
while enemigo > 0 and enemigo < 10000:

 
    print ('\n\n **** Utilice a, b o c para seleccionar el ataque deseado **** \n')
    player = input(' Seleccione el ataque que quiere utilizar: ')

    if player == "a":
        ataque = a
    elif player == "b":
        ataque = b
    elif player == "c":
        ataque = c
    else:
        ataque = 0
        print ('\n Por favor, selecciona un ataque valido')
        continue

    ...
```

Comment: Lo intenté hacer, pero no me funcionó. Gracias igual :)